# How to fix ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR for only one specific site

Tags: macos, security, web-browser, certificate, ssl

Working on a site for a client, and for some reason I keep getting the "can't provide a secure connection" error in ALL browsers. Everyone outside me seems to see it fine. If I log in to my work computer with a VPN, it works fine.

I've look at tons of articles on this error. Yes, my time is set correct, I've cleared my cache and so forth.

I even tried copying over the SSL cert to my login keychain and select trust always, and this didn't work. It seems like browsers have been updated and they don't allow you to "trust anyway" anymore.

This is my friend's company, it has a valid certificate and I know the site is fine. I need to allow this site to work in order to get my work done.

I'm on a late 2013 iMac running Catalina 10.15.1.

Comment: Which site it is?

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same symptoms. In my case when I try to use my Logitech Media Server (LMS, port 9000) that is on a different port on the same machine as my Open Media Vault (OMV, port 80 for http & 443 for https) file server and Unifi Network (port 8443) applications.

OMV & Unifi have Let's Encrypt certificates to support validated SSL certificates, LMS does not. And that is where the problem comes in. One or both of OMV & Unifi have Chrome demanding an SSL certificate from LMS, which it can't provide leading to the error.

Something about the web site, or the way you access it, is creating a similar circumstance. Does the company use a secure proxy to provide certification?

In my case, clearing the dns cache at chrome://net-internals/#dns resolves the problem for at least a little while. This thanks to https://superuser.com/questions/1077503/chrome-err-ssl-protocol-error-on-known-working-site.